# What do the R, 3m, and 5 mean in the Am chord?

Tags: guitar, theory, chord-theory

I know as much that R means Root note, but what does the rest mean?

[image]

Comment: May I ask where this image is from; some chord app? A nice illustration.

Comment: Yup, a paid one. I downloaded it from Google Play, here's the link :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rabugentom.chord&hl=en_US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dchord!+(guitar+chord+finder)+rebugen+tom+google+play&pcampaignid=APPU_1_fI03W42KL8yy9QPD6ZfQDQ

Comment: where did you get this image? I love how the chord is weighted.

Comment: @AntonioFDelgado It's from a mobile app called 'chord!'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**R** means the root of the chord (A), **3m** would refer to the minor third of the chord (C), and **5** to the fifth (E).

Comment: You can also have 3M (major third) and major/minor 7ths, 9ths, 11ths, or 13ths.

Comment: @GeneralNuisance Wouldn't the "3" alone imply the major third?

Comment: @Jacob Swanson It's certainly possible. The 5 in the example is actually a major fifth. You can also have diminished chords which use minor third and minor fifth intervals: R 3m 5m.

Comment: Classical ("Old") music theory books distinguish major intervals with an "M", e.g. M3, M6, M7, as opposed to m3, m6, m7.  In modern music no symbol is taken to be Major by default, except in the context of a 7th chord, X7 is assumed to be dominant 7th (flat 7th).

Comment: The 5 is a perfect fifth, not  a major fifth. There is no major or minor for fifths of fourths. Most tones have diminished, minor, major, augmented, but fifths and fourths just have diminished, perfect, and augmented.

Comment: @JacobSwanson Yes, but as ggcg explained, I've seen it both ways. In fact, in Certificate of Merit tests, the capital Ms are generally required when naming intervals.